# error on passing from controller to views in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

i want to passing data from model to controller then to view 
this code explain it.

> the model

```
public function get_all_college_name() {
    $q = $this -> db -> query('select * from college');
    if ($q -> num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($q->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

> the controller code

```
public function index() {
    $this -> load -> model('retriver_data');
    $data['rows'] = $this -> retriver_data -> get_all_college_name();

    $this -> load -> view('home', $data);

    //$this -> view_something('home', $data);
}
```

> the view code

```
<body>
    <?php
    foreach ($rows as $r) {
        echo $r -> name;
    }
    ?>
</body>
```

the error appears

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
>
> Filename: views/home.php
>
> Line Number: 8

Comment: Where is `$rows` defined?

Comment: @RUJordan $data['rows']  is the query working ? Also make sure you return an empty array if query fails

Comment: do var_dump($data)  before sending to view 
probably it is not correct format

Comment: $rows defined in controller

Comment: @user1281385  how i do it?

Comment: @Biswajit what the correct format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For CI, in my models I usually use:

```
if ($query->num_rows() == 0)
    return FALSE;

return $query->result_array();
```

then if your view you'll check if the array is false before displaying

```
<body>
    <?php if ( ! $rows) : ?>
        no data
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php foreach ($rows as $row): ?>
            <?php print $row->name; ?>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</body>
```

Comment: suggest that you do the If results check in your controller - then call the appropriate view.